# Trying to pass the selected value from select to a function, n amount of times in an array

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a dynamic table where the user can select the amount of rows. Each row has 2 dropdowns with 1-10 to choose from. Each time the user selects a number from the dropdown I want it to pass to a function in the TS file to do stuff. The problem I am having is I am trying to use ngModel to pass the data back to the TS file. When I do this though every dropdown that was created in the dynamic table obviously sets itself to that value. What is the best way to simply pass a value back to the TS file without the need for 2 way binding?

My HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table">
<thead class="thead-light">
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:center">{{blueFighter}}</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Round</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">{{redFighter}}</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tablerows">
  <tr *ngFor="let round of rounds; index as i">
    <td id="{{'redScore'+i}}" align="center">
      <ng-select class="form-group"
                 style="width:50%"
                 [(ngModel)]="inputValueRed"
                 [items]="score"
                 (change)="updateRedScore($event, i, inputValueRed )"></ng-select>
    </td>
    <td align="center">{{i + 1}}</td>
    <td id="{{'blueScore'+i}}" align="center">
      <ng-select class="form-group"
                 style="width:50%"
                 [(ngModel)]="inputValueBlue"
                 [items]="score"
                 (change)="updateBlueScore($event, i, inputValueBlue)"></ng-select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="font-weight:bold">
    <td>{{redScoreSum}}</td>
    <td align="center">FINAL SCORE</td>
    <td>{{blueScoreSum}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

TS:

```
export class MyScorecardComponent implements OnInit {
   redFighter: String;
blueFighter: String;
numOfRounds: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
score: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
redRoundByRound: number[];
blueRoundByRound: number[];
redRoundScore: number[];
selectedRounds: number = 1;
rounds: number[];
inputValueBlue: number;
inputValueRed: number;
blueScoreSum: number;
redScoreSum: number;
tableArray: any[];



createCardClick() {
this.rounds = Array(this.selectedRounds).fill(0).map((x, i) => i);
 }


updateBlueScore($event, index, passedscore) {
 this.blueRoundByRound[index] = passedscore;
}

updateRedScore($event, index, passedscore) {
 this.redRoundByRound[index] = passedscore;
}
```

Part of the HTML is missing but that part works fine.

Comment: It seems that there many areas that you still don't know. keep learning.tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to bind the select to a model.
Try

```
      <ng-select class="form-group"
             style="width:50%"
             #select="ngModel"
             ngModel
             [items]="score"
             (change)="updateBlueScore($event, i, select.value)"></ng-select>
```

So, just give the ng-select a name (with the '#' in front of), add the ngModel directive and pass it's value as a parameter.

Comment: I get a "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" when I try that. Can the name property be repeated? There would be multiple elements with that name since the table repeats n amount of times.

Comment: Ok. I thought this would be no problem. Try to remove the #select and add "#select="ngModel" name="select-{{i}}"  ngModel" to your select.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `FormArray` class (reactive design). Here is pseudo code :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup(
      {
         'rounds':new FormArray([]);
      }
    }
```

You can have a method like this the to add new row :

```
  addRound() {
    const control = new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
    (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('rounds')).push(control);
  }
```

template file :

```
... 
<tr *ngFor="let round of myForm.get('rounds').controls; index as i">
...
<ng-select [formControlName]="i" >
...
```